# How do I use Text in SwiftUI to display an array of tuple values?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have declared an array of tuples as such:

```
    var countryFlag: [(flag: String, description: String)] = [("", "United States"), ("", "South Korea"), ("", "Phillipines"), ("", "Canada"), ("", "Germany")]
```

I am trying to call and display these values in an HStack using Text(), but my error is:

**use of unresolved identifier 'flag' and 'description'**

here's my whole code :

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport


struct ContentView: View
{
    var countryFlag: [(flag: String, description: String)] = [("", "United States"), ("", "South Korea"), ("", "Phillipines"), ("", "Canada"), ("", "Germany")]
    
    var body: some View
    {
        List(0..<5)
        {
            item in
            HStack
                {
                    Text("\(flag)")
                    Text("\(description)")
                }
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List(0..<5) { item in` loops 5 times and `item` takes on the values of `0` though `4`.  Those are indices into your `countryFlag` array.  Subscript `countryFlag` with `item` which will then give you a tuple.  You can then access the values in that tuple with `.flag` and `.description`.

Replace:

```
Text("\(flag)")
Text("\(description)")
```

with:

```
Text("\(countryFlag[item].flag)")
Text("\(countryFlag[item].description)")
```

---

A better way to go about this would be to `List` your `countryFlag` array using `\.flag` as the `id`.

```
List(countryFlag, id: \.flag) { item in
    HStack {
        Text("\(item.flag)")
        Text("\(item.description)")
    }
}
```

Finally, if you use `flag, description in` in the closure to deconstruct the tuple into two variables, you can use the `Text` views as you defined them:

```
List(countryFlag, id: \.flag) { flag, description in
    HStack {
        Text("\(flag)")
        Text("\(description)")
    }
}
```